# Map master/detail records after Dapper calls

Tags: data-modeling, dapper

At work, we're considering using `Dapper`. In the existing code base, our master/detail objects are loaded separately. Typically, this means that there is one sql statement executed for all master records and one sql statement executed per detail record.

To improve performance and ease the transition, I'd like to make 2 calls using `Dapper` and stitch the results together:

```
public class Zoo
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set;}
    IList<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; }
}

public class Monkey
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    Guid ZooId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool DeservesBanana { get; set; }
}

var sqlZoos = "SELECT * FROM Zoos"
var Zoos = connection.Query( sqlZoos )

var sqlMonkeys = "SELECT * FROM Monkeys"
var Zoos = connection.Query( sqlZoos )

foreach( var zoo in Zoos )
{
  zoo.Monkeys = Monkeys.Where( x => x.ZooId = zoo.Id ).ToList();
}
```

Is there a helper method or something in `Dapper` that I can use to replace the `foreach`. Should I use something like `AutoMapper` instead? Or is there a better way to achieve this (than the `foreach` loop) using the .NET library?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var zoos = new Dictionary<string, Zoo>();
var query = "SELECT * FROM Zoos LEFT OUTER JOIN Monkeys ON Monkeys.ZooId = Zoos.Id";

_connection.Query<Zoo, Monkey, Zoo>(query, (z, m) =>
{
    if (!zoos.TryGetValue(z.Id, out Zoo zoo))
        zoos.Add(z.Id, zoo = z);

    zoo.Monkeys.Add(m);
    return zoo;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ultimately, I want to rewrite our code to do a single SELECT statement. However, there is a _lot_ of code that needs to be re-written. Devising the simplest way to stitch data together after multiple queries will allow us to introduce `Dapper` with the the least amount of friction